# What to do if I get ping results for non-existing hosts?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ping

When I am pinging non-existing host like 'zzz' or 'qwerty'

I am getting the following result

```
Pinging zzz.kanisa.com [209.62.20.200] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 209.62.20.200: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=46
Reply from 209.62.20.200: bytes=32 time=66ms TTL=46
```

It looks like a virus to me. But I was unable to find a solution on web. Any ideas how to fix it?

Even more ridiculous results with nslookup

```
C:\> nslookup google.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com.kanisa.com
Address:  209.62.20.200
```

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For name lookup, the DNS client uses DNS Suffixes which can be changed here for Windows XP:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient\SearchList
```

Comment: Aha, I somehow thought your were on a Mac. I'm sure there is some "Advanced" setting in some dialog for that on Windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) entry for *.kanisa.com which points at that IP. That means that even if there is no website hosted for that subdomain, all non-explicitly defined entries for that domain point to 209.62.20.200, which, apparently, responds to ICMP ECHO requests.

Comment: Sounds like exact answer to me. I wonder how I can fix it. I cannot reproduce it on my second laptop so I guess it is local issue.

Comment: IF you have "kanisa.com" set as a search domain in your network connection preferences, anything you ping from that one location that isn't fully qualified will append kanisa.com to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You will be interested to notice that I get similar results too :-)

```
$ ping zzz.kanisa.com
PING zzz.kanisa.com (209.62.20.200): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 209.62.20.200: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=390 ms
```

So,

1. `zzz.kanisa.com` resolves the same way for all
   Nothing special in `zzz.kanisa.com` resolving to `209.60.20.200` for you
2. But, **why does `zzz` get converted to `zzz.kanisa.com` for you?**
   That means, you have `kanisa.com` as your local domain name.
   Is that expected? If so, `ping abc` would also look for `abc.kanisa.com`
   And, resolve to the same IP (wildcard DNS as MarkM explains).

So, the real question becomes: Is `kanisa.com` your default domain name?

Comment: No, it is not my domain name. Although I am not sure what default in this context means.

Comment: @bublegumm, see the default *search* domain, in your network preferences, Advanced, DNS, like [here](http://img.skitch.com/20100508-pqmefw7gx18n47wrxpkx6kgy6s.png).